# XCODE failed to create Repositories History

Tags: xcode, version-control, repository

I'm newbie to Swift Code and having a confusion with Xcode Repository when trying to test out how it works. Seems XCODE fail to create Repository History if we COMMIT with some CHANGES remained UNSTAGED.

Let's say, I was at version #3 of the Repositories History, and there was only 1 branch - the MAIN branch

I made 7 changes in my codes and STAGE only 5 of them. Then I clicked SUBMIT. The progress produced no error yet, except I couldn't find the version history in the Repositories Navigator - there's no version #4.

After that, I SWITCH from current to version #3. Of course, I was required to STASH the 2 UNSTAGED CHANGES. After the progress SWITCHING finished, I literally back to the version #3 and lost all the 5 STAGED CHANGES earlier. The only CHANGES that remained was 2 STASHED CHANGES.

MY QUESTION:

**IS IT NORMAL WHEN XCODE FAIL TO CREATE REPOSITORIES HISTORY IF WE COMMIT WITH CERTAIN CHANGES REMAIN UNSTAGED ?**